# Make checksum function faster

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, checksum

This checksum calculation will be called many times: Is it possible to make the following checksum function work faster?

I'm particularly wondering if it is possible to get rid of the for loops (as I'm told those are slow in python).

```
sred = b'Standa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008MR191-28'\
       b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'\
       b'\x00\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc'\
       b'\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xe9\xa8'  

def _check_crc(bstring): 
    crc = 0xffff 
    for b in bstring: 
       crc = crc ^ b 
       for i in range(8): 
          carry_flag = crc & 0x0001 
          crc = crc >> 1 
          if carry_flag == 1: 
              crc = crc ^ 0xa001 
    return crc

_check_crc(sred) # will give 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is a well known algorithm (crc16-modbus) and there is python module ([libscrc](https://pypi.org/project/libscrc/)) that can be used to calculate the checksum. I tested it and it is way faster then the original code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This code is about 10% faster on my machine:

```
def _check_crc(bstring):
    crc = 0xffff
    for b in bstring:
        crc = crc ^ b
        for i in range(8):
            if crc & 0x0001:
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001
            else:
                crc = crc >> 1
    return crc
```

This is mostly due to the elimination of the assignment to `carry_flag`. The boolean comparison `if crc & 0x0001:` could also be a bit faster than comparing vs. 1.

There might be other possible improvements, but the only further idea that I have right now is trying to implement the function in C. However, I don't know how much faster this will be. The bitwise operations should already be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would probably be to use a 65536 entry lookup table; something like:

```
def _check_crc(bstring): 
    crc = 0xFFFF00 
    for b in bstring:
       crc = lookupTable[crc | b]
    return crc >> 8
```

Note: I've "pre-shifted" the CRC and all values in the table to the left by 8 bits to remove a shift from the middle of the loop (instead of doing `crc = lookupTable[ (crc << 8) | b]`).

The table/list itself could be run-time generated, or explicit (e.g. by printing out a run-time generated list and cut&pasting it directly into your source code). I'm too lazy (and don't remember enough Python) to show example code for run-time generation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just something I don't quite understand: the lookup table size: you wrote it should be a 16 bit (65536) large, but I'm getting 24 bit one (to accommodate all combinations of 16 bit crc and 8 bit b). Did I miss something?

Comment: @AsenChristov: Ah - sorry.. For a 16-bit CRC it would've been a 24-bit index and a 16777216 entry table. However, with that CRC algorithm only the lowest 8 bits of the old CRC matter for the index (because only the lowest 8 bits get used by the `if carry_flag == 1: `), so you can use a 65536 entry table with `crc = (crc >> 8) ^ lookupTable[(crc & 0xFF00) | b]`